connecting with Mysql using langchain SQLDatabase.from_uri
I'm connecting my MySQL database using LangChain. I am getting the following error. Can anyone help please. Thanks.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\H.USAMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 644, in connect
sock = socket.create_connection(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\H.USAMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 827, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\H.USAMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
My code is :
import openai    
import os
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_community.utilities.sql_database import SQLDatabase`

#from langchain.chains import SQLDatabaseSequentialChain

from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv()) # read local .env file   

openai.api_key = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']

username = "username" 
password = "password" 
host = "xyz.amazonaws.com" 
port = 3306
mydatabase = "database_name"


mysql_uri = f"mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{mydatabase}"

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(mysql_uri)

